# rails project using omniauth - stuck on evaluating nil.[] error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth

I am using omniauth on my rails project to authenticate with facebook.

I am also trying to get the user's current city from omniauth, and that works great when the user has their current city in facebook.

extra: 
  user_hash: 
    name: Jeff Turner
    location: 
      name: Oakland, California

but when the user doesn't have anything, I cant set that value

```
current_city = user_data['location']['name']
```

**error:
You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of ActiveRecord::Base.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.[]**

I can see that no value with those attributes even come back from omniauth

if I try to test for the nil condition

```
if user_data['location']['name'].blank? == false
current_city = user_data['location']['name']
end
```

I seem to get the same error on that first line (user_data['location']['name'].blank?)

still cant evaluate nil.

I am pretty new to rails, so I hope I just missed something obvious.

**Update**

this is what I ended up changing it to and it worked fine.  answer below looks like it would work as well

```
if user_data['location'].nil? == false
  if user_data['location']['name'].nil? == false
   current_city = user_data['location']['name']
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try doing something like this:

```
current_city = auth.fetch('location', []).fetch('name', nil)
```

Using [fetch](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-fetch).

Comment: Thanks for the response, that looks like it would fix it too.   we ended changing it last night and I forgot to update this.

Comment: It's ok! Fetch is really handy and it's a nice tool to have around :)

Comment: I've just been working on this same issue.  I hadn't found this answer at the time, but I was getting the same error.  The above answer gave me the error *no implicit conversion of String into Integer* What I used in the end was:

    user.town = auth.info.location.try {split(",")[0]} || ""

I have tried lots of variations and many end in an unhandled exception.  If anyone has a "foolproof" way to get the location, please post as an answer below- thanks.